# hsqldb standalone mode from java webapp

Tags: java, connection-pooling, hsqldb

I am working on a java webapp (Spring 4, Jpa 2, Hibernate 4, HikariCp 2.3.8) that connects to hsqldb 2.3.3 . 
My customer reported a lock after testing for a brief time with "Database Lock Acquisition Failure".
I am using a jdbc url like this:

jdbc:hsqldb:file:/path-to-database/maindb;shutdown=true;hsqldb.write_delay=false;

I have two doubts:
 - it is correct to use the standalone file mode of hsqldb in a "connection pool" context? I was wondering if this lock is due to the fact that the database can be opened just for one process at a time in standalone mode.
 - it is correct to use shutdown=true in a "connection pool" context? it is not constantly doing shutdown on database when closing each connection? what happens to the others?

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database can indeed be opened just for one process at a time. You need a server to manage connections from multiple processes. The "Database lock acquisition failure" is always thrown when a second process attempts to connect directly.

It's fine to use file mode with a connection pool as all the connections are from the same process. Running a server is preferable as you have access to database outside the web app.

Note shutdown=true is provided for use in test contexts and shouldn't be used here. An explicit SHUTDOWN should be issued when required.